# Excel sum all column values until reach certain sum then export last summed cell range address or filter sum range

Tags: excel, vba, filter, sum

Tried several hours to find an answer,  no luck.
Got excel sheet with  column A where column A with numbers like 1,2,3,6,6,3,4,5,6
I want sum column values from top until reach 20 or less, then exports address of last value used in sum or
best would be  make auto filter select all these values full rows and delete them.
I guess VBA can achieve that .
Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Delete Rows ('Sum Less Than')

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRows()
    
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const sSum As Double = 20
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With Range(sFirst)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim cSum As Double
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If IsNumeric(Data(r, 1)) Then
            cSum = cSum + Data(r, 1)
            If cSum > sSum Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If r > 1 Then
        rg.EntireRow.Resize(r - 1).Delete
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are the man ! Thank You so much .Really appreciate. No surprise I cant find and answer  , bit  to much complicated  than my skills capable for